# Select filed from Array of Hashes in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

So i have this Array of Hashes

```
{"id"=>50823, "code"=>"1PLAK", "name"=>"Eselente", "order"=>1}
{"id"=>74327, "code"=>"1MAGP", "name"=>"Mango", "order"=>2}
{"id"=>50366, "code"=>"1ANGC", "name"=>"Tabnie", "order"=>3}
{"id"=>76274, "code"=>"1FABD", "name"=>"Slamtab", "order"=>4}
```

And i want to select the field `order` (just one field at the same time) for comparing afterwards.
What's the correct way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Question is unclear. What's the expected output.?

Comment: in the first hash will be 1
in the first hash will be 2
in the first hash will be 3
in the first hash will be 4

I'm just looking for 1 field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you only want to extract the values of the orders then I would do this:

```
array = [
  {"id"=>50823, "code"=>"1PLAK", "name"=>"Eselente", "order"=>1},
  {"id"=>74327, "code"=>"1MAGP", "name"=>"Mango", "order"=>2},
  {"id"=>50366, "code"=>"1ANGC", "name"=>"Tabnie", "order"=>3},
  {"id"=>76274, "code"=>"1FABD", "name"=>"Slamtab", "order"=>4},
]
array.map { |hash| hash["order"] }
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

When you are only interested in the very first value (`1` like you wrote in the comments above) then you can do:

```
array.first["order"] # or array[0]["order"]
#=> 1
```

Comment: He says `for comparing afterwards`

Comment: I agree that it is not clear what the OP meant by _"for comparing afterwards"_. But I would argue that you can compare integers in an array with something else...